# Unique combination of columns

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

here is my simplified data set:

```
foo <- data.frame(var1= c(1:10), var2=rep(1:5,2),var3=rep(1:2,5),var4=rep(3:7,2) )
```

all together 20 variables

```
foo

   var1 var2 var3   var4    ... var20
1     1    1    1      3
2     2    2    2      4
3     3    3    1      5
4     4    4    2      6
5     5    5    1      7
6     6    1    2      3
7     7    2    1      4
8     8    3    2      5
9     9    4    1      6
10   10    5    2      7
```

I need to get a unique combination of 3 variables and its sum for each period

ie. sth like

```
  var1var2var3   var1var3var4   var1var5var18  etc...
1     6               sum
2     6           
3     7          
4     10           
5     11           
6     9         
7     10             
8     13          
9     14          
10    17
```

note that var1var3var5 is the same as var3var1var5

Comment: Are you solving for an arbitrary dataset or this specific one? There might be optimizations for this one. Also, your first solution data point seems like it should be 3, not 6 (row 1, first column)

Comment: It seems like `combn(20,3)` could be useful here to generate the unique combinations of all columns. How to turn that into something to reference each column in an `apply` or `for loop` is a bit beyond me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Chase suggested, `combn` gets you what you want:

```
nams <- apply( combn(colnames(foo),3), 2, function(z) paste(z, collapse = ''))
cols <- combn( ncol(foo), 3)

tripleSums <- apply( cols, 2, function(z) rowSums(foo[,z]))
colnames(tripleSums) <- nams

> tripleSums
      var1var2var3 var1var2var4 var1var3var4 var2var3var4
 [1,]            3            5            5            5
 [2,]            6            8            8            8
 [3,]            7           11            9            9
 [4,]           10           14           12           12
 [5,]           11           17           13           13
 [6,]            9           10           11            6
 [7,]           10           13           12            7
 [8,]           13           16           15           10
 [9,]           14           19           16           11
[10,]           17           22           19           14
```

Comment: @Alex, try accepting this answer as the correct one (by clicking the check mark under the vote score).