# Performing adf test on a data.frame

Tags: r

I can perform an adf test on a vector:

```
library(tseries)
ht <- adf.test(vector, alternative="stationary", k=0)
```

but I am having trouble  performing it on columns of values in a data.frame:

```
ht <- adf.test(dataframe, alternative="stationary", k=0)
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: `lapply` is going to be your friend. The answer is going to be something like `lapply(dataframe, adf.test, ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the  pvalues of all the variables in one table you can us ldply from the plyr package.

```
pvalues=ldply(ht, function(x){ x$p.value })
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ht <- lapply(dataframe, adf.test, alternative="stationary", k=0)
```

should do the trick as [@Andrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/602276/andrie) pointed out. It will return you a list with an element for each column in the dataframe

Comment: What I am looking for is a function similar to the excellent corr function : df.cor <- cor(df) # get correlations, but for a measure of cointegration rather than correlation. So in a similar way, a dataframe containing a number of dataseries will be converted into a matrix containing adf values for each pair in the dataseries.

Comment: so something like: ht <- apply(combn(colnames(dataframe,2), 2, function(colnames,data) your.test(y[,colnames]),data=dataframe) or as mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081311/r-unique-combination-of-columns